# mysql 5.7 how to update JSON data in longtext field

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I have a longtext field with data stored in JSON format:

```
[   
{
        "name": "Internal_use",
        "id": "InternalUse_mv_rec",
        "fields": [
            {
                "d_on": "1",
                "like": "1",
                "length": "150",
                "show": "1",
                "pattern": "",
                "caption": "mv_previous_cr",
                "type": "1",
                "script": "",
                "preview_on": "1",
                "search": "1",
                "name": "mv_previous_cr",
                "options": "",
                "btn_caption": "",
                "open": "1"
            },
            {
                "d_on": "1",
                "like": "1",
                "length": "100",
                "show": "1",
                "pattern": "",
                "caption": "mv_previous_pn",
                "type": "2",
                "script": "",
                "preview_on": "1",
                "search": "1",
                "name": "mv_previous_pn",
                "options": "",
                "btn_caption": "",
                "open": "1"
            }
        ],
        "cata_key": "cata_.1568937511545431466",
        "open": "1"
    }
]
```

I would like to update "length" to 200 for "name": "mv_previous_cr" using mysql query. How can I do that?

mysql version: 5.7.28
Please note that this data is stored by a third-party app and I cannot modify the data type.

Thanks!

Comment: *I have a longtext field with data stored in JSON format* Why you do not use JSON column datatype?

Comment: The answer depends on the data. If it is possible only one property `"name": "mv_previous_cr"` per the whole value then the query can be simple. Otherwise you need in either iterative stored procedure or additional synthetic numbers table.

Comment: @akina as I mentioned, this is a third-party app and I cannot modify the actual database. I can use their gui to change the value but it is a time consuming process. So I was hoping to change the data in the db directly. I also tried to export this table, modify the value and import back, but that did not work well for some reason.

Comment: My comment contains hidden question about the possible amount of properties to be replaced. Please answer it. Anycase you may use textual function (REPLACE) for to solve..

Comment: @Akina The data is exactly same as what I have put in the question. In the JSON document, I see "name": "mv_previous_cr" is there one time. Hope this answers your question.